Standard definition of a game in game theory
Sorry for my naive question, but at the moment I can't quite figure it out.
I'm consulting various documents on game theory in order to get the standard definition of what a game (and an associated strategy) is.
But I have the impression that from one book to another I get a different definition, and it's not presented as ‘equivalent’ to the others (maybe it is).
So I often come across definitions with an associated qualifier like ‘normal form game’ or ‘strategic game’ but never what a ‘game’ is. It's as if I only get definitions of what a simple group or an abelian group is in group theory, but I don't have the definition of a group beforehand.
So I'm sorry to bother you with what is surely the most naive question ever: What is a game?
I have this definition of a normal form game from the replies to this message on the forum:
Definition of game in game theory

A game in normal or strategic form is a triplet $G = (I, (S_i)_{i \in
 I}, (h_i)_{i \in I})$, where:

$I$ is the set of Players ($I = \{1, \ldots, n\}$).
For each $i \in I$, $S_i$ is Player's $i$ set of strategies, where $\prod_{i \in I} S_i$ is the set of strategy profiles.
For each $i \in I$, $h_i : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the payoff (von-Neumann-Morgenstern utility) function on the set of strategy
profiles. Implicitly, it is as if we had an outcome function $g : S \rightarrow A$ and a utility function $u_i : A \rightarrow
 \mathbb{R}$. Then, for every $s \in S$, set $h_i(s) = u_i(g(s))$.


And this definition of a strategic game from this document :
https://arielrubinstein.tau.ac.il/books/GT.pdf

A strategic game consists of:

a finite set $N$ (the set of players)
for each player $i \in N$ a nonempty set $A_i$ (the set of actions available to player $i$)
for each player $i \in N$ a preference relation $\succeq_i$ on $A = \times_{j \in N} A_j$ (the preference relation of player $i$).


And on the Wikipedia page I couldn't find any definition of what a game is:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory
The hypothesis I have at the moment is that there is a kind of equivalence between the two definitions by the theorem of Von Neumann–Morgenstern : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Morgenstern_utility_theorem
which would give the equivalence between giving an order on actions and giving a utility on actions ? But I don't master either of these notions and normally I wanted to start at the beginning: the definition of the object studied.
Thank you very much for your answers. I hope you have a very good day.
Additions:
There is also the 89.1 definition of an 'extensive game with perfect information' in https://arielrubinstein.tau.ac.il/books/GT.pdf :

An extensive game with perfect information has the following
components.

A set $N$ (the set of players).
A set $H$ of sequences (finite or infinite) that satisfies the following three properties.

The empty sequence $\emptyset$ is a member of $H$.
If $(a_k)_{k=1,\ldots,K} \in H$ (where $K$ may be infinite) and $L < K$ then $(a_k)_{k=1,\ldots,L} \in H$.
If an infinite sequence $(a_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ satisfies $(a_k)_{k=1,\ldots,L} \in H$ for every positive integer $L$ then
$(a_k)_{k=1}^\infty \in H$.
-(Each member of $H$ is a history; each component of a history is an action taken by a player.) A history $(a_k)_{k=1,\ldots,K} \in H$
is terminal if it is infinite or if there is no $a_{K+1}$ such that
$(a_k)_{k=1,\ldots,K+1} \in H$.
The set of terminal histories is denoted $Z$.


A function $P$ that assigns to each nonterminal history (each member of $H \setminus Z$) a member of $N$. ($P$ is the player
function, $P(h)$ being the player who takes an action after the
history $h$.)
For each player $i \in N$ a preference relation $\succeq_i$ on $Z$ (the preference relation of player $i$).



There are lots of different types of game - are you referring to games with perfect information, for example?

Not every preference relation gives a utility function, if an action set is infinite. So these definitions aren't actually equivalent. But you're probably not going to come across any preferences for which this fails to be equivalent. Having a utility function also allows you to extend to a mixed strategy game, which you can't do if you only have a preference relation.

Thanks for your answer.
Is there no general definition of what a game is in itself?
(Like a group in group theory, although there are many different types of group. Or a vector space or a manifold etc).

Consider for example the lexicographic ordering on $\mathbb{R}^2$. There is no utility function that produces those preferences.

Thanks for your answer Zoe, is there a definition of what a game is in general?

I don't think you can give a general definition of a game. I mean, algebra is the study of algebraic structures, but can you define what an algebraic structure is, precisely? Game theory studies many different types of games, each of them has a different definition.

Thank you for your reply Jean Abou Samra.
There is indeed a general definition of what an algebraic structure is in model theory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic)).
Similarly, in Group Theory we define what a group is in the general sense, in Category Theory we define what a category is, in Graph Theory we define what a graph is, in Field Theory we define what a field is, in Scheme Theory we define what a scheme is, in Set theory etc.
What about game theory?
But I understand that things didn't work out that way. That was simply my question.

Yes, universal algebra exists, but defining algebra as the study of structures as defined in universal algebra would kind of miss the point, since algebra is mainly about some specific structures (groups, rings, fields, vector spaces, etc.). Another example: logic. There are some general definitions of what a logic is (abstract logic), but they are rather obscure and more of something searched after the fact to encompass various specific logics than a definition which pervades the field. Combinatorics is also a good example of a field that doesn't lend itself to a precise definition.

And that is just fine. A subfield of math/CS doesn't need to define itself precisely in formal terms. It is made of a set of similar objects, of common methods, of a network of theorems and conjectures, and of a research community.

Thank you for this exchange.
I'm not really sure that it's necessary to have a unifying notion of what a game is, even if unification often seems to me to bring richness to mathematics.
It doesn't seem to me that this is only the case in algebra, for example with topological spaces, measurable spaces or differential manifolds; it seems to me that there is a central object of study which is then specified and broken down into several cases to create precise fields of study and results.
I understand that this is not the case for game theory.

There are various forms of mathematical games, often expressed as tuples. The first common part of all of them is a set $N$ of players with $|N|\ge 2$. The second common part is the assumption that players can decide independently and their decisions impact other players' decisions (their utility functions can depend on all players' decisions; or more generally, the preference relation of each player depends on the other parleys' decisions). Because of these two common parts, an alternative name for game theory is multi-person decision making (optimization).
If the utility function of each player only depends on their decision, then we have $|N|$ separate optimization problems. Indeed, for $|N|=1$, we have single-person decision making (optimization).

Generally, the second definition is more general than the first.
Case 1. If the players do not consider stochastic (mixed) strategies (only pure-strategy profiles are chosen), then both games become the same if the preference relations of all players have two properties of completeness and transitivity. In this case, the preference relation $\succeq$ can be represented by some utility function $u: \prod_{j \in N} S_j \to \mathbb R$ as follows for any $s,t\in \prod_{j \in N} S_j$:
$$ s \succeq t \Longleftrightarrow  u(s) \ge u(t).$$
Case 2. For the case where the players consider stochastic (mixed) strategies, first let me update the second definition as follows:

A strategic form mathematical game, compactly denoted by  $\left (N,\{S_i\}_{i\in N}, \{\succeq_i\}_{i\in N} \right )$, basically used for modeling static games with complete information where the players decide simultaneously, consists of

a finite set $N$ (the set of players)
for each player $i \in N$ a nonempty set $S_i$ (the set of pure strategies available to player $i$)
for each player $i \in N$ a preference relation $\succeq_i$ on $\Delta \left ( \prod_{j \in N} S_j \right ) $, which denotes the set of all product probability measures $F=\bigotimes_{i = 1}^{n} {F_{i}}$ on the set $\prod_{i \in N} S_i$, where each measure $F_{i}$ represents the stochastic strategy of player $i$ on set $S_i$.


When all players are von-Neumann-Morgenstern (vNM) rational decision makers (whose preference relations have four properties of completeness, transitivity, continuity, and independence [1]), instead of working with preference relations, we can work with utility functions (similar to the first definition); hence, we can show the game by the 3-tuple $\left (N,\{S_i\}_{i\in N}, \{u_i\}_{i\in N} \right )$. This follows from the fact the preference relation $\succeq$ of any vNM rational decision maker can be represented by the expectation of some utility function $u: \prod_{j \in N} S_j \to \mathbb R$ as follows for any $F,G\in \Delta \left ( \prod_{j \in N} S_j \right)$:
$$ F \succeq G \Longleftrightarrow  \mathbb E_{X\sim F} (u(X)) \ge \mathbb E_{X\sim G} (u(X)).$$

Note that one may consider other types of preference relations (see e.g., [2] and  [3]), whose representations (if exist) differ from the above.
I need to remake that going beyond vNM preference relations may be interesting from an applied perspective, but it restricts us from having nice and general results such as the existence of Nash equilibria for any finite static games with vNM rational players.
Moreover, the classical static games can be extended in other directions such dynamic games, Bayesian games (a type of games with incomplete information), etc. In the above answer, I only focused on your specific question on how the static game can be extended by considering an arbitrary preference relation for each player.

Extensive form mathematical games are only used for modeling dynamic games, in which players may not decide simultaneously.
You can formulate a static game as each of strategic or extensive form mathematical game, but the latter adds nothing more in analyzing the game. On the other hand, you can model a dynamic game as each of strategic or extensive form mathematical game, but in this case the former cannot properly reflect the dynamics of the game.

In the above I used the term mathematical game to help you to distinguish mathematical objects (strategic form, extensive form, Bayesian forms, etc.) that we call games, often expressed as some tuples, from   games (static, dynamic, etc.) that we encounter in practice, often expressed by some descriptive statements (mathematical games are also called game in many references for shortness, which may be confusing for newcomers).

Thank you very much for your detailed answer, it's really helpful.
I'm sorry I didn't get back to you more quickly, but I read it as soon as you posted it.
I get the following message when I click on the top arrow: "Thanks for the feedback! ‘You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.’"

I was wondering: reading these definitions, I get the impression that most ‘games’ in the classic sense of the term fall into the ‘extensive game with perfect information’ structure. Am I wrong?
In any case, the nuances and interests you point out help me to picture things.

@u31672873 You are welcome!  It is wrong. Extensive form games with perfect information does not support simultaneous moves (they cannot be used for modeling static games). However, general extensive form games (which can support imperfect information case) seems to be the most general classic mathematical games for modeling games with complete information.

Thank you very much for your reply.
If I understand correctly, are ‘extensive/perfect’ appropriate to represent turn-based strategy games (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn-based_strategy) while ‘extensive/imperfect’ are appropriate for real-time strategy games (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_strategy)?

@u31672873  Yes, that's right
